# taylor polynomial, find an upper bound on the error using Pn(0.5)

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

for a given n, let Pn(x) be the $n^{th}$ degree taylor polynomial of  $f(x)=x^2e^{x-1}$ about point  $x=1$,

What I got so far is,

$R_n(0.5)=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, c between x and a,

and from previous calculation,

$f^n(x)=n(n-1)e^{x-1}+2nxe^{x-1}+x^2e^{x-1}$,so

$f^{n+1}(x)=n(n+1)e^{x-1}+2(n+1)xe^{x-1}+x^2e^{x-1}$,

choose c=1

$R_n(0.5)=\frac{(n(n+1)+2n+3)(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, c between x and a,

I know I have to find expressions $>=$ to above equation, but I can't seem to get a nice answer,

the questions from textbook all have very simple final answer, like $\frac{6}{5}$, $\frac{1}{n!}$

btw, is it ok to justwrite
$R_n(0.5) <= \frac{f^{n}(c)(x-a)^{n}}{(n)!}$, since error of $R_n(0.5)$ will always be greater or equal to $R_{n+1}(0.5)$

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula use is wrong. When you use formula $$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
$x$ is the point you are evaluating the Taylor polynomial, $a$ is the point where you expanded the Taylor polynomial, and $c$ is a point between $x$ and $a$.

Thus you should have used $a=1, x=0.5$, then you have $$R_n(0.5)=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(0.5-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(n(n+1)+2(n+1) c+c^2)e^{c-1}(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

usually you only want the absolute value of $R_n(x)$, so you get 
$$|R_n(0.5)|=\frac{(n(n+1)+2(n+1) c+c^2)e^{c-1}}{(n+1)!2^{n+1}}$$

which, since $c\in [0.5, 1]$, is a monotonically increasing function in $c$. So take $c=1$ as the upper bound and you get
$$|R_n(0.5)|\leq\frac{n^2+3n+3}{(n+1)!2^{n+1}}$$